# Do we need php-js tag? There is a phpjs tag, but it is different from PHP-JS?

Tags: discussion, tags

I've recently started to use this [PHP-JS](https://github.com/CopernicaMarketingSoftware/PHP-JS) library.

And I need some help 'talking' to it.

So I tried to add a question with a [php-js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/php-js) tag. This was the result:

> You are attempting to create the tag [php-js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/php-js); however the tag [phpjs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/phpjs) already exists! If you think this new tag should be allowed, raise it on [meta](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/).

The two libraries are different, so adding [php-js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/php-js) would make some sense.

**So the main question here is:**

Can we add the new tag or do I post the question without it, although it might help having it there?

Comment: It would be *enourmously* confusing to have a [tag:php-js] tag and a [tag:phpjs] tag *that both referred to different things.  There would really need to be a more notable difference in the tag names, to have any semblance of appropriate tagging.

Comment: Should I use `copernica-php-js`? Would that eliminate the confusion?

Comment: Solution: Get rid of all things PHP.

Comment: @Will even my job :(?

Comment: @TomHart you'll get a *better* one.  One that doesn't involve ... ugh, I don't want to say it.

Comment: @Will so I'd get a new job where I don't have to use the Pretty Horrible Programming language? Sign me up!

Comment: @TomHart, be careful what you wish for :)) you might become a ... javascript developer

Comment: @AlexTartan *shudders* please, no!!!

Comment: "PerHaPs we should JettiSon [tag:php-js]?"

Comment: I agree with @Servy ; it would be *enormously** confusing to have two nearly identical tags that refer to totally separate things. This is a rare scenario though, where one author probably didn't realize there's already a PHP JS out there... tough call.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, big thanks for all your input.

Indeed it would have been *enormously* confusing.

So I created [copernica-php-js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/copernica-php-js).